# Display Data for Logged in User in model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Django version 2.2

I have models in django

```
class Class_teacher(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    empid = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    standard = models.IntegerField()
    division = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' --  ' + str(self.school)


class Student(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    classteacher = models.ForeignKey('Class_teacher', on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    reg_id = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    parent_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent_second_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

views for adding student

```
class StudentCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = '/signin/'
    model = Student
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'parent_first_name','parent_second_name', 'email', 'reg_id']
    success_url = '/dashboard/'
```

The webapp has login feature as below ,

```
def signin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)

                return HttpResponseRedirect('../dashboard/')

            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your account was inactive.")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details given")
    else:
        return render(request, 'webapp/login.html')


def dashboard(request):
        email = request.user.email
        if Class_teacher.objects.filter(email__iexact=email).count() == 1:
            students = Student.objects.values('classteacher')
            context = { 'students' : students}
            return render(request, 'webapp/dashboard.html',context)
```

dashboard.html template

```
{% if students %}
    <ol>
        {% for student in students %}
        <li>{{student.first_name}} {{student.last_name}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ol>

{% else %}
    <h3>No Students Added</h3>

{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I used `students = Student.objects.values('classteacher')` but it doesnot provide with students names , just display an ordered list numbers .

I have two requirements

1. I have a modelform where the logged in teacher can add students , while I am adding students using the first mentioned view above it is triggering an error 'NOT NULL constraint failed: webapp.classteacher_id' , and when I change the add views to below it works well

```
class StudentCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = '/signin/'
    model = Student
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'parent_first_name','parent_second_name', 'email', 'reg_id' , 'classteacher']
    success_url = '/dashboard/'
```

What i Want with the studentadd view is students should be added under the respective logged in teacher without providing the teacher's value via form

2. After login , the dashboard have to display students of the respective logged in teacher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [filtered](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) your students incorrectly.

Try this:

```
def dashboard(request):
    email = request.user.email
    class_teacher = Class_teacher.objects.get(email=email)
    students = Student.objects.filter(classteacher=class_teacher)
    return render(request, 'webapp/dashboard.html', {'students': students})
```

Comment: It's working well for the second requirement , i have one more requirement mentioned in the question .

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea what you mean by the first question, can you clarify a bit?

Comment: I have updated the question and has included code also .

Comment: the first StudentCreate is giving the error after submitting the form , it got fixed by adding the necessary fields in the view , but that doesn't solve the issue,  i want to add students unders the classteacher without providing classteache value since teacher is already logged in

Comment: The reason that is happening is because your Student model doesnt currently allow for a blank classteacher field. You can fix this by adding blank=True and null=True to the foreignkey and then migrating.

Comment: The errors are fixed after adding blank=True and null=True  , but it doesn't add my student under the logged in teacher , as i mentioned , logged in teacher should be able to add students under him without choosing the classteacher . Error has been fixed with your solution but when I check via admin panel , teacher is still unchosen .

Comment: To do that you would need to customize the CreateView to automatically assign the teacher to each student. You can follow the answer here and assign self.request.user (the teacher) to the Student: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49857733