# How to estabalish ManyToMany relationship on instantiation of object through generic CreateView?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

So I have two models. Deck and Card. When the user creates card it should be tied to a deck, in a ManyToMany relationship.

The card is created through the Generic Django create view, and I can't crack how I can assign the card to a deck, in this context. Any ideas on how I might solve this?

My CreateView

```
class CardCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Card
    fields = ['question', 'answer']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.creator = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('spaced_repitition-home')

    def assign_card(self, deck_id): #It's here I don't get why it doesn't work
        card = self.get_object()
        deck = get_object_or_404(Deck, pk=deck_id)
        card.decks.add(deck)
        card.save()
```

Template that sends user to form (passes on deck_id)

```
{% for deck in decks reversed %}
   <a href="{% url 'card-create' deck_id=deck.id %}">
      <p> Add Card </>
{% endfor %}
```

Form Template

```
{% extends "spaced_repitition/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{%  block content %}

  <div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <fieldset class=form-group>
        <legend class="borders-bottom mb-4"> Create Card </legend>
          {{ form|crispy }}
      <div class=form-group>
        <button class= "btn btn-outline-info" type="submit"> Create </button>
      </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>


{% endblock content %}
```

Models

```
class Deck(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Card(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    answer = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    decks = models.ManyToManyField(Deck)
    days_till_study = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question + ' pk: ' + str(self.pk)
```

Url

```
path('card/new/<int:deck_id>/', CardCreateView.as_view(), name='card-create'),
```

Thanks for reading this.

**Edit**

Found the solution here:
[Django Createview default value for a foreign key field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49857585/django-createview-default-value-for-a-foreign-key-field/49857733#49857733)

Comment: How about `deck.card_set.add(card)` instead of `card.decks.add(deck)`?

Comment: Didn't change anything, unfortunately.